# How to get reference to navigationcontroller in tableview searchbar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have setup in storyboard a navigation controller and a tableview controller. There is a search bar in the tableview.
I get a reference to the navigation controller using self.navigationcontroller. 
I use

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

To hide the navigation bar in the subsequent view which is displayed.
This works fine when selecting a cell in the tableview without using the searchbar.
However, if I use the searchbar to display specific cells in the table view and if I select a cell from that table, then apparently I lose the reference to the navigation controller because although the above code is executed, the navigation bar is still displayed in the follwing view.

What should I do to hide the navbar??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found: The NavigationBarHidden property is apparently reset because when the searchbar leaves the view, it will send the navigationbar again on the view. I am not sure I understand exactly what is happening, but this line of code in my viewWillDisappear solves the problem:

```
 self.searchDisplayController.active=NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you execute that line of code on the following viewcontroller?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but it does not work. The navbar is still displayed